# I am having problems combining input functions, for-loops and if-statements on my code

Tags: python, input

hope you all doing fine. I am having a little situation with my code. I am trying to create a program where the user gets to create their own username, then this username is compared to a list of existing users. The problem is that when the user tries to type in their own username, the program goes ahead and loops each letter through the existing list and then gives you a prompt. What I really want to have the program doing is to evaluate the input (username word) as whole and compare it to my existing list.

```
current_users=['gin','obi','joe','chris','ralph']

new_users=input('enter user name:')

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user in current_users:

        print(f"{new_user} is already taken, please choose another username")

    else:

        print('username succesfully created')
```

I am guessing there is a theoretical concept that I have not gotten down yet. If you guy can help me fix the code, Id appreciate it.

Comment: `new_user` isn't a list. when you loop it your will just get the letters. You can do this instead: `if new_user in current_users:`

Comment: Looping a `string` loops letter-by-letter - you're unnecessarily looping it in a `for` structure.

Comment: Did you mean to allow the user to input multiple usernames?

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating through the new username (character by character), in fact, no iteration is needed on your part, just use `in`:

```
if new_users in current_users:
    print(f"{new_users} is already taken, please choose another username")
else:
    print('username succesfully created')
```

You can also use `if new_users.lower() in map(str.lower, current_users)` if usernames are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" loop is looping through the letters in the input. Eliminate the "for" loop and it should work.

```
current_users=['gin','obi','joe','chris','ralph']

new_users=input('enter user name:') 

for new_user in new_users: #note that new_users is the string you just asked for, you're looping through each character. 

    if new_user in current_users:

        print(f"{new_user} is already taken, please choose another username")

    else:

        print('username succesfully created')
```

Comment: it's the code from the OP. I copied it and added a comment explaining where it's going wrong and how. It's not my code.

Answer (score 0):

new_users is a string, therefore `for new_user in new_users` loops through the characters of the string, not the words... If you expect multiple users, you could split the string and loop through the resulting array.

i.e usernames seperated with spaces

```
new_users = 'bob bill jim tod'  # result of an input let's say
new_users = new_users.split()   # default splits by ' '
# current code
```

or as @MrGreek mentioned. you could just skip the loop and go straight to the `in` statement.